# Update Error: E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Tags: 19.10

I've seen this error in the forums several times, but my issue comes when running the suggested command. When I run `sudo apt-get install` I get the error `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`. Then, I run the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, and the command runs but hangs indefinitely. I think this is due to some virtualbox installation. I've tried removing files from `dkpg` with `rm` but that doesnt seem to help. The output of the suggested command is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libopenshot-audio6 libopenshot17 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libvpx5
  linux-headers-5.0.0-37 linux-headers-5.0.0-37-generic
  linux-image-5.0.0-37-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-37-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-37-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
27 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up systemd-sysv (242-7ubuntu3.9) ...
Setting up libfreerdp2-2:amd64 (2.1.1+dfsg1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) ...
Setting up libnss-systemd:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.9) ...
Setting up libisc1100:amd64 (1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up thunderbird-locale-en (1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.19.10.2) ...
Setting up apport (2.20.11-0ubuntu8.9) ...
apport-autoreport.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Setting up thunderbird-locale-en-us (1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.19.10.2) ...
Setting up thunderbird-gnome-support (1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.19.10.2) ...
Setting up apport-gtk (2.20.11-0ubuntu8.9) ...
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (242-7ubuntu3.9) ...
Setting up libisccc161:amd64 (1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.0.14-dfsg-1) ...
Removing old virtualbox-6.0.14 DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  virtualbox
Version: 6.0.14
Kernel:  5.3.0-51-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

vboxdrv.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.3.0-51-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetadp.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.3.0-51-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetflt.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.3.0-51-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxpci.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.3.0-51-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.0.14
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-6.0.14 DKMS files...
Building for 5.3.0-51-generic
Building initial module for 5.3.0-51-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

vboxdrv.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.3.0-51-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.3.0-51-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.3.0-51-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.3.0-51-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...
```

Once the terminal gets to `depmod...` it hangs indefinitely. I've let it sit for hours. Any suggestions? Running Ubuntu 19.10.

Per request, output of the command `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'` is

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-===========================================================-===========================================================-============-===============================================================================
iU  aptdaemon                                                   1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu28.2                                    all          transaction based package management service
iU  bind9-host                                                  1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.2                               amd64        DNS lookup utility (deprecated)
iU  ca-certificates                                             20190110ubuntu0.19.10.1                                     all          Common CA certificates
it  dbus                                                        1.12.14-1ubuntu2                                            amd64        simple interprocess messaging system (daemon and utilities)
it  desktop-file-utils                                          0.24-1ubuntu1                                               amd64        Utilities for .desktop files
iU  dnsutils                                                    1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.2                               amd64        Clients provided with BIND
it  gnome-menus                                                 3.32.0-1ubuntu1                                             amd64        GNOME implementation of the freedesktop menu specification
it  hicolor-icon-theme                                          0.17-2                                                      all          default fallback theme for FreeDesktop.org icon themes
it  initramfs-tools                                             0.133ubuntu10                                               all          generic modular initramfs generator (automation)
iU  libbind9-161:amd64                                          1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.2                               amd64        BIND9 Shared Library used by BIND
it  libc-bin                                                    2.30-0ubuntu2.1                                             amd64        GNU C Library: Binaries
iU  libdns-export1104                                           1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.2                               amd64        Exported DNS Shared Library
iU  libdns1104:amd64                                            1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.2                               amd64        DNS Shared Library used by BIND
iU  libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64                                  2.1.1+dfsg1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1                                amd64        Free Remote Desktop Protocol library (client library)
iU  libirs161:amd64                                             1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.2                               amd64        DNS Shared Library used by BIND
iU  libisccfg163:amd64                                          1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1ubuntu2.2                               amd64        Config File Handling Library used by BIND
it  man-db                                                      2.8.7-3                                                     amd64        on-line manual pager
it  mime-support                                                3.63ubuntu1                                                 all          MIME files 'mime.types' & 'mailcap', and support programs
iU  openssl                                                     1.1.1c-1ubuntu4.1                                           amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility
iU  python3-aptdaemon                                           1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu28.2                                    all          Python 3 module for the server and client of aptdaemon
iU  python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets                               1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu28.2                                    all          Python 3 GTK+ 3 widgets to run an aptdaemon client
it  shared-mime-info                                            1.10-1                                                      amd64        FreeDesktop.org shared MIME database and spec
iU  virtualbox                                                  6.0.14-dfsg-1                                               amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
iU  virtualbox-qt                                               6.0.14-dfsg-1                                               amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
```

Comment: can you show `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'` maybe an important package is in bad condition.

Comment: added in the edits. the output is rather large

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, make a backup from your important data.

```
wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools_0.133ubuntu10_all.deb
```

and try to install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i initramfs-tools_0.133ubuntu10_all.deb
```

This part from your question I do not understand.

> I've tried removing files from dkpg with rm

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install
```

Only then this is without errors.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Comment: why do i need to backup my data? is there some risk to doing something harmful if i run this?

Comment: there are some packages affected. It could be it is not repaired so easily; besides it is always good to have an current backup.

Comment: okay ill give this a try and accept if it works, thank you

Comment: I had to choose the correct version from here: http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your file was missing.

This is the solution that I have tried:

You must install `initramfs-tools` deb package,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install initramfs-tools
```

and try

```
sudo apt updgrade
```

The problem should be fixed now.

Comment: `sudo apt updgrade` I think there is a spelling error, is it upgrade or update! And stop using `apt-get` use just `apt`

Answer (score 0):

I solve it. First remove the **dpkg** updates

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates
sudo rm *
```

Then you should update the packages and remove what is no longer used

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Good luck! Credits: https://brandviser.com.au/how-to-fix-dpkg-was-interrupted-error-linux/